# How do I develop a new resource bundle on Grails?

Tags: grails

I'd like to create a resource bundle to organize my Grails app.

How can I create a new resource bundle?

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to start. M just reading about resource bundle n didn't get where to start

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a file under `grails-app/i18n/` with the `.properties` extension.  Grails will automatically discover the file and make the messages available via the `messageSource` bean in the Spring application context and to tags like the `<g:message ...>` tag.

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/i18n.html for more details.